# R - how to pick a random sample with specific percentages

Tags: random, sample

This is snapshot of my dataset

```
A   B
1   34
1   33
1   66
0   54
0   77
0   98
0   39
0   12
```

I am trying to create a random sample where there are 2 1s and 3 0s from column A in the sample along with their respective B values. Is there a way to do that? Basically trying to see how to get a sample with specific percentages of a particular column? Thanks.